# Looping over a string list and making values lowercase

Tags: makefile

I have a Makefile, trying to loop over a series of strings in a recipe and make them lower case.

My goal: I have a series of commands I would like to run on different files with the appropriate suffix.

```
# files in directory: test_file1.txt test_file2.txt test_file3.txt
MYLIST = file1 file2 file3
recipe:
    for name in $(MYLIST) ; do \
        $(eval FILENAME=`echo $($name) | tr A-Z a-z`) \
        
        echo "Final name : test_${FILENAME}.txt" ; \
        
    done
```

My problem, FILENAME always resolves to blank:

```
File name: test_.txt
```

I hope to see:

```
File name: test_file1.txt
File name: test_file2.txt
File name: test_file3.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mix make functions and shell commands like this.  Make works like this: when it decides that your target is out of date and it wants to run the recipe, **first** it will expand the entire recipe string.  **Second** it sends that expanded string to the shell to run.

So in your case, the `$(eval ...)` (which is a make operation) is expanded one time, then the resulting string is passed to the shell to run.  The shell runs the for loop and all that stuff.

You have to use *shell* variables here to store values obtained by running your shell for loop.  You cannot use make variables or make functions.

In general if you ever think about using `$(shell ...)` or `$(eval ...)` inside a recipe, you are probably going down the wrong road.

Comment: As a hint, you can just examine the command that make prints out before the output you showed us above.  That is the command string make passes to the shell.  You'll find that where the `$(eval ...)` was in your recipe, is just an empty space in the command make sends to the shell.